# taks skipping to JavaExec task when inputs remainded unchanged

Tags: gradle

I need to introduce a bytecode enhancemnt step in my gradle configuration. I was able to configure my JavaExec task accordingly, but Gradle won't skip it, even if the declared inputs are recognised as 'up-to-date':

```
task lazyEnhance(dependsOn: [compileJava, processResources]) {
  inputs.files(compileJava.outputs.outputFiles)
  outputs.files(compileJava.outputs.outputFiles)

  doLast {
    println "Doing bytecode enhancements..."
  }
}

task datanucleusEnhance(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: [compileJava, processResources]) {
  classpath = configurations.compile + sourceSets.main.output.with { files(it.classesDir, it.resourcesDir) }
  main = 'org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer'
  args = "-api JPA -pu DictionaryModels".tokenize()

  inputs.files(compileJava.outputs.outputFiles)
  outputs.files(compileJava.outputs.outputFiles)
}

//this action task is skipped as intended
classes.dependsOn(lazyEnhance)

//the 'real' enhancement task of type JavaExec, however, is never skipped
classes.dependsOn(datanucleusEnhance)
```

(You can find the complete build script here for further context: https://gist.github.com/neradis/7830434)

Is it hard-wired behaviour of Gradle to assume that Exec tasks should always be executes, regardless of unchanged inputs? If so, can this be changed a single JavaExec task declaration, if not, what is the workaround that can be seen as as close possible to best practice? (Starting the actual JavaExec task in a doLast action closure of lazyEnhance would probably do the trick, but if I remember correctly, manual invocation of tasks from wihtin other tasks is no recommended/poor build design...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is this declaration:

```
inputs.files(compileJava.outputs.outputFiles)
outputs.files(compileJava.outputs.outputFiles)
```

Here you say, that the task output points to the same files as the task inputs. That does not work, because the task will always be out of date because

1. first run: (new generated input -> new generated output)
2. next run: (compilation runs again because its output has changed (by your bytecode enhancing in the prior run). Due to the enhanced classes where replaced by the compile task, your enhanceByteCode task needs to run again. ...

You should always use seperate folders for tracking input and output of a task. Furthermore overwriting the output of another task is bad practice and result in non incremental builds/unpredictable build results)

cheers,

René